# MYSQL Search data from json field where datas position might differ

Tags: mysql, mysql-json

I have table where i have to find ID when i only know for example dcid:xxxxxx which can be found in different places in IDENTIFIERS column

```
+----ID----+--------------------------------IDENTIFIERS-----------------------------------+
|  234512  | ["ident:2392392", "id2:292930", "dcid:291013"]                               |
|  564344  | ["ident:9402933", "dcid:29101", "id3:2092819"]                               |
|  655656  | {"1":"ident:0291911", "2":"id2:9522211", "3":"id3:8877543", "4":"dcid:92366"}|
+----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Use common string-processing functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
SELECT ID FROM mytable
WHERE JSON_SEARCH(identifiers, 'dcid:291013');
```

The [JSON_SEARCH() function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-search) returns the JSON path to the value if it can find it, regardless of the position or type of JSON document. If the value cannot be found anywhere, then JSON_SEARCH() returns NULL.

This query cannot be optimized with an index. It will be bound to do a full table-scan, so it will get more and more slow as your table grows.

My standard recommendation is if you need to use JSON functions to search data in the WHERE clause, then it's a strong indicator that you should store data in normal rows and columns, not in JSON.